# Why do I have no entries in Screen Layout in Bookworm/Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, display, screen, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I recently moved to Pi 4 and installed Bookworm using the Imager.  I then switched to X11 from Wayland and changed the resolution - both using raspi-config. I also set a static address and finally created an autostart file under ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

I have setup chromium to load in kiosk mode, but it only occupies a quarter or so of the screen.  So I commented out most of the autostart file and now I only have:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
```

When I go to Preference->Screen Configuration and then choose Layout->Screens I see the below:

[image]

Note: Right now, I don't have a monitor so I am seeing this through VNC...

**Edit:** I just got my monitor, and now the view in VNC is correct.  The monitor however, flickers and ends up with a pixelated image with incorrect colors.

I think the Pi goes into Headless mode when a monitor is not connected.  How do I correct that?

Comment: "installed Bookworm using the Imager … switched to X11? Why bother? Apart from the desktop & a new version of python there is little change from Bullseye.